# get first element after a space

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
1-8-2015 10:00 PM
```

How to with only one line to return just 1-8-2015? below is an attempt but it's 2 line.

```
var date = $('datetime').text().split(' ');
console.log(date[0])
```

Comment: `var date = $('#datetime').text().split(' ')[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `datetime` is an id then use a `#` before it and use `[]` after [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) as it will return an array,

```
console.log($('#datetime').text().split(' ')[0]);
//-------------^-- use # here --------and ---^--- for getting it in single line
```

```js
alert($('#datetime').text().split(' ')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="datetime">1-8-2015 10:00 PM</span>
```

Comment: that could be a typo... as OP is getting the o/p required... OP just want to the operation in 1 line instead of 2